# Check if div child elements changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't get it.
Shouldn't this code work?

**Here the HTML-Code**

```
<div id="past">
    <div data-rollid="283585" class="ball ball-1">7</div>
    <div data-rollid="283586" class="ball ball-1">4</div>
    <div data-rollid="283587" class="ball ball-8">11</div>
    <div data-rollid="283588" class="ball ball-8">14</div>
    <div data-rollid="283589" class="ball ball-1">2</div>
    <div data-rollid="283590" class="ball ball-1">5</div>
    <div data-rollid="283591" class="ball ball-1">2</div>
    <div data-rollid="283592" class="ball ball-1">6</div>
    div data-rollid="283593" class="ball ball-8">13</div>
    <div data-rollid="283594" class="ball ball-1">3</div>
</div>
```

**And here the jQuery-Code**

```
$('#past').one('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    var stuff = $('#panel8-14 .mytotal').html();
    var test = '-';
    if( test.indexOf(stuff) >= 0){
        console.log('asdf');
    }
    else{
        console.log('nope');
}
```

});

The Problem is:

- When i do it with this code and use the .one() function then it calls the function only once at the first loading and not when the div content changes...
- When i do it with .bind or with .on then i gives it back 2 times...

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant, but there is an error in the html. "div data-rollid="283593" class="ball ball-8">13</div>" is missing the leading "<"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Justin should not be the problem

Comment: @guest271314 i want to execute a jquery statement when the content from #past changes...

Comment: How does content in `#past` change?

Comment: @guest271314 every minute or something it adds a new "ball" and deletes the oldest one

Comment: @Tykon _"When i do it with .bind or with .on then i gives it back 2 times"_ Because a `node` is both removed from `document`, and `node` is added to `document` _"every minute or something it adds a new "ball" and deletes the oldest one"_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver`

```js
var target = $("#past").get(0);

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

    if (mutation.removedNodes.length) {
      console.log("removed nodes", mutation.removedNodes[0].nodeValue);
      alert("removed nodes");
    }

    if (mutation.addedNodes.length) {
      alert("added nodes");
      console.log("added nodes", mutation.addedNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }

  });
});

var config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true,
  characterData: true
};

observer.observe(target, config);

$("#past div:first").text(1); // do stuff
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="past">
  <div data-rollid="283585" class="ball ball-1">7</div>
  <div data-rollid="283586" class="ball ball-1">4</div>
  <div data-rollid="283587" class="ball ball-8">11</div>
  <div data-rollid="283588" class="ball ball-8">14</div>
  <div data-rollid="283589" class="ball ball-1">2</div>
  <div data-rollid="283590" class="ball ball-1">5</div>
  <div data-rollid="283591" class="ball ball-1">2</div>
  <div data-rollid="283592" class="ball ball-1">6</div>
  <div data-rollid="283593" class="ball ball-8">13</div>
  <div data-rollid="283594" class="ball ball-1">3</div>
</div>
```